# Oracle-Trigger for testing the number of students in a class

Tags: oracle, plsql, count, database-trigger

I am trying to create a before insert trigger which restricts the number of students in a group, I mean, if the number of students in a group is greater than 5, the user can't introduce any other record in this same group but he can in others where there are less than 5 students.

In the table I have this information:

[image]

So the trigger should let adding records in all of the rows except into the second one because there are already 5 students there.

I tried the following code:

```
create or replace trigger groups_capacity
 before insert on s183410_group
  for each row

  declare
   counter INTEGER;

 BEGIN 
    select count(*)into counter from s183410_group group by class_id;

        if counter>5 and :old.class_id=:new.class_id then
            raise_application_error(-20002,'This class is full.There cannot be more than 5 students in the same group.');
        end if;

END;
```

I think that the counter does not change it value for each row. I am new in oracle and don't know really how to use it.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Statement Trigger`,  in which to check whether any of the groups by class_id violates the rule, but not a `Row Level Trigger` in order not to get mutating trigger error :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER groups_capacity
  AFTER INSERT ON s183410_group

DECLARE
  counter INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) INTO counter FROM s183410_group GROUP BY class_id;

  IF counter > 5 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20002,
                            'This class is full.
                             There cannot be more than 5 students in the same group.');
  END IF;
END;
```